# Loading layer from PostGIS with non-unique primary key

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to load (by mean of PyQGIS) a layer from PostGIS based on query involving a inner join with a non-spatial table. When I run the query in pgAdmin I get the desired output but when I integrate that query in my PyQGIS code I get an error message from QGIS saying that the primary key of the layer is not unique.

How can I load the layer since it is the result of a join between two table and obviously doesn't have a primary key ? (DB manager can load table without unique primary key, how can I do that with PyQGIS?)

**Code sample:**

```py
self.sql_test = """
(SELECT a.field1, b.field1, a.field2 FROM (SELECT w.field1, w.geom, ST_INTERSECTION(v.geom, w.geom)
FROM schema1."table1" v, schema2."table1" w
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(v.geom, w.geom) AND v.table3 LIKE 'AR457') as a
INNER JOIN (select * from schema2.table4)as b on a.field1=b.field1)
"""

self.uri.setDataSource("", self.sql_test, "geom", "", "par_id")

self.test= QgsVectorLayer(self.uri.uri(), "test", "postgres")
if not self.test.isValid:
    print('Chargement de la couche: echec !')
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.test)
```

Comment: When I add that part in my query and run the code again, QGIS says that the relation "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id, a.field1, b.field1, a.field2" does not exist even though it works fine in pgadmin

Comment: Actually I forgot to close a parentheses ! It works fine now, thanks !
If you post your comment as a reply I could accept it as an answer

Comment: The reason a primary key is wanted is to tie features to attributes. Unfortunately, using `row_number` can generate unintended results if feature "1" is filtered by a query envelope and is actually the fifth record is the return results. Then there's the possibility that the return order changes depending on the whim of the optimizer when an ORDER BY is not provided. Be careful with `row_number`.

Comment: @Vince: I agree, this solution is mainly to load the PostGIS query into QGIS and never use this field after.

Comment: You can also use the `ctid` attribute, which is an internal system column that shows the physical location of the row version within its table.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html and 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html
A tuple ID is a pair (block number, tuple index within block) that identifies the physical location of the row within its table

Comment: To expand a bit on @vince and @J. Monticolo comments, the `order by ` clause should be mandatory here (`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tbl1.id, tbl2.id, tbl2.whatever_to_make_row_order_unique) `). It is not only a matter of purposely using the field later, but of QGIS using it in your back. For instance, the order the features are returned could be different when displaying the geometries and when loading the attribute table, effectively disconnecting the geometries from their attributes.

Comment: If there's a spatial constraint (not all the data is in the map view), then row_number values map be different, and a highlight using `WHERE row_number_col = 1` could return a completely different record.

Comment: @all: I deleted my comment, and recommend the Vince and JGH answers.